# iPad Mini: Swift-App receive memory warning on low usage

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, crash, memory-warning

i have a problem with my iOS-App programmed in Swift. I programmed an app which play different content types (Video, Image, Websites) in different views. But after a short time i run the app, the app receive a memory warning, but the memory usage of my app is about 20mb. So there is no reason for this memory warning. After a while the app crashes. Is it a bug from Swift, my iPad or anything else?
I add a screenshot of the memory usage:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6WEN.jpg

Best regards,
seb

Answer (score 0):

deallocate MPMovviePlayerController after video stop stop playing

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I forget which Object Type i use to display my different content. Website: WKWebview ; Video: AVPlayer ; Image : ImageView

Comment: Finding a solution. Using MPMoviePlayerController instead of AVPlayer. It seems like the AVPlayer is starting a process which increase the Memory usage on "Other processes" and this make the small free memory to small.